# How to use a function and its derivative('s) to solve another differential equation in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, differential-equations, derivative, odeint

I need to solve this two equations simultaneously in python :
[image]
"b" is constant; but I don't know how to put the function "P" and its derivative at same time in the second equations code,
is there anyone could help me?

edition:
I have wrote this code to solve the question, but I don't know it is correct or not. is this code correctly gives the answer of those equations?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as sy
import sys
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
b=2
def eq(t,u):
    #u[0] is p and u[1] is p', u[2]=y, u[3]=y'.
    u[1]=u[0]*np.sqrt(0.25*(u[0]**-4)*(u[0]+(1/7)+0.7)
    return [u[0],u[1],u[3],-3*(u[1]/(b*u[0]))*u[3] - u[2]]
u0 = [0.00001,0.00001,1.22*(10**28),0]
t = np.linspace(0.0000000001,0.6924*10**33,10000)
sol=solve_ivp(eq,t,u0,None)
```

Comment: Hi, danial. Try defining the expression for what is p and then a new one for dp. and you can use both p and dp separately, tip: dont use "/" in variable names. / is a expression for math division.

Comment: @GuilhermeNicchio thank you for your comment, i have edited the post and uploaded the equations  , dp/dt is not a name but its derivative with respect to time  .please take a look and comment if its possible; thanks again.

Comment: You have a state vector with 3 components `p, y, dy = u`. Next you compute the root expression `r=R(p)`. Then `return p*r, dy, -3*r*dy/b-y`. This gives a nice ODE function where the solver solves the coupled equations simultaneously.

Comment: @LutzLehmann   thanks, is this what you mean?

Comment: No, you return just the derivatives of the components of the state vector. `p'=p` is not in the system, but is the equation of the first component in the implemented function.